# Determinant and Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

What is answer to this question?

Start with the polynomial $\det(A − λI)$ separated into it's $n$ factors (why is this always possible?). Then set $λ = 0$:

$$\det(A − λI) = (λ_1 − λ)(λ_2 − λ) \cdots (λ_n − λ) \text{ so } \det A = ?$$

I'm not too sure where to start.

Comment: $(\lambda_1-0)\dots(\lambda_n-0)=\lambda_1\dots\lambda_n=\det(A).$

Comment: Why do you set $\lambda =0$ unless that is an eigenvalue? you compute $$\det (\mathbf{X}-\lambda \mathbf{I}) = (X_{11}-\lambda)(X_{22} - \lambda)\cdots $$ etc..

Comment: This is a question straight from the book. I'm not too sure what the author is trying to show with this? How can we right the detmerinant as such?

Comment: Setting $\lambda = 0$ you get that the determinant is equal to the product of all the eigenvalues!

Comment: And you can always write it like that by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra I guess? Supposing that is an $n \times n$ matrix

Comment: @mfl: If $\det(A-\lambda I)=(\lambda_1-\lambda)\dotsm(\lambda_n-\lambda)$ , then $\det(A-5 I)=(\lambda_1-5)\dotsm(\lambda_n-5)$, for instance, and $\det A=\det(A-0I)=(\lambda_1-0)\dotsm(\lambda_n-0)=\lambda_1\dotsm\lambda_n$.

Comment: But why can we wrtie it like that? we have no guarantee that this is a triangular matrix so just blindly multiplying eigen values won't work

Comment: It is not always possible if you search exactly for real eigenvalues. However if the universe of discourse is the field of complex number, than you can always write it like that. And so you'll have your determinant. And the great thing is that complex roots of polynomial always come with pairs, such that their multyplication is always real number. So your determinant will always be real number. And will be equal to the product of the eigenvalues.